# WebGL Vertex Shader fails to compile and 'WebGLRenderingContext :' parameter 1 is not of type 'WebGLProgram'

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

When I try to run the code below in my browser I receive a pop-up notification that "Vertex shader failed to compile.  The error log is:

```
<pre>ERROR: 0:11: 'assign' :  cannot convert from 'highp 3-component vector of float' to 'Position highp 4-component vector of float'
</pre>
```

Followed by the console error message:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'useProgram' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': parameter 1 is not of type 'WebGLProgram'.init @ tangram2.js:76"
```

I am trying to create several 2-D shapes (just one for now, as a proof of concept), each with their own buffer, so that I may translate and rotate them on the GPU individually.

```
"use strict";`
var canvas, gl, program;
var points = [];
var colors = [];
var shapeScale = (1/3);

/* RGBA colors */
var vertexColors = [
    vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // black
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // yellow
    vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // green
    vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // blue
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // magenta
    vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // white
    vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 )   // cyan
];

/* Shader transformation matrices */
var modelViewMatrix, projectionMatrix;

/* Rotational indicies */
var LT1 = 0; /* Large  triangle 01 */
var LT2 = 1; /* Large  triangle 02 */
var MT1 = 2; /* Medium triangle 01 */
var ST1 = 3; /* Small  triangle 01 */
var ST2 = 4; /* Small  triangle 02 */
var SQR = 5; /* Square */
var PRL = 6; /* Parallelogram */

var theta = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

var modelViewMatrixLoc;

/* For each shape, create a vertex and color buffer */
var vLT1Buff, cLT1Buff;
var vLT2Buff, cLT2Buff;
var vMT1Buff, cMT1Buff;
var vST1Buff, cST1Buff;
var vST2Buff, cST2Buff;
var vSQRBuff, cSQRBuff;
var vPRLBuff, cPRLBuff;

/* ----------------Initialize webGL---------------- */
window.onload = function init(){
    /* From robotArm.js */
    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );
    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }
    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
    gl.enable( gl.DEPTH_TEST );

    /* Setup canvas background */
    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);

    /* Load shaders and use the resulting shader program */
    program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );

    /* Create an initialize buffer objects */
    vLT1Buff = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vLT1Buff );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    cLT1Buff = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cLT1Buff );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor );

    modelViewMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "modelViewMatrix");

    projectionMatrix = ortho(-10, 10, -10, 10, -10, 10);
    gl.uniformMatrix3fv( gl.getUniformLocation(program, "projectionMatrix"),  false, flatten(projectionMatrix) );

    //-------------------------------------//
    //          Initialize Shapes          //
    //-------------------------------------//

    var largeTriangle01 = setupTriangle( 1, Math.sqrt(2) / 2);
    var largeTriangle02 = setupTriangle( 1, Math.sqrt(2) / 2);
    var medTriangle01   = setupTriangle( Math.sqrt(2) / 2, 0.35);
    var smallTriangle01 = setupTriangle( 0.5, 0.25);
    var smallTriangle02 = setupTriangle( 0.5, 0.25);

    /* Add our shapes to an array of shapes for quick access */
    var shapes = [
        largeTriangle01,
        /*
        largeTriangle02,
        medTriangle01,
        smallTriangle01,
        smallTriangle02,
        square01,
        */
    ];

    for(var i = 0; i < shapes.length; ++i){
        scaleShape( shapes[i] ); //Scale our shapes
        makeShape ( shapes[i] ); //And draw them
    }

    render(LT1);
}//end init

/* ----------------Helper funcitons---------------- */

//TODO dont forget about Parallelogram!

/* From robotArm.js */
function scale3(a, b) {
   var result = mat3();
   result[0][0] = a;
   result[1][1] = b;
   return result;
}

/* Return an array of three points representing a triangle */
function setupTriangle(hypotenuse, height){
    return [
        vec4( hypotenuse / 2, height, 0.0, 1.0 ),
        vec4( hypotenuse  , 0, 0.0, 1.0 ),
        vec4( 0, 0, 0.0, 1.0 ),
    ];
}//end setupTriangle

/* Return an array of four points representing a quad */
function setupRectangle(width, height){
    return[
        vec4( -width,  height, 0.0, 1.0),
        vec4(  width,  height, 0.0, 1.0),
        vec4(  width, -height, 0.0, 1.0),
        vec4( -width, -height, 0.0, 1.0),
    ];
}//end setupRectangle

function scaleShape(shape){
    for( var i = 0; i < shape.length; ++i ){
        shape[i] = scale( shapeScale, shape[i] );
    }
}//end scaleShape

function makeShape(shape){
    if(shape.length == 3){ makeTriangle (shape); }
    if(shape.length == 4){ makeQuad     (shape); }
}//end makeShape

function makeTriangle(listOfPoints){
    for(var i = 0; i < listOfPoints.length; ++i){
        points.push(listOfPoints[i]);
    }
}//end makeShape

function makeQuad(listOfPoints){
    points.push( listOfPoints[0] );
    points.push( listOfPoints[1] );
    points.push( listOfPoints[2] );
    points.push( listOfPoints[0] );
    points.push( listOfPoints[2] );
    points.push( listOfPoints[3] );
}//end makeShape

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

function largeTriangle01(){
    // var s = scale3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    var instanceMatrix = translate(0.5, 0.5);
    var t = mult(modelViewMatrix, instanceMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix3fv(modelViewMatrixLoc,  false, flatten(t) );
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, points.length );
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
function render(shape){
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    modelViewMatrix = rotate(theta[shape], 0, 1, 0);

    switch(shape){
        /* Large Triangle 01 */
        case 0:
            largeTriangle01();
            break;
    }//end switch

    requestAnimFrame(render);
}//end render
```

My shaders are:

```
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec3 vPosition;
        attribute vec4 vColor;
        varying vec4 fColor;

        uniform mat3 modelViewMatrix;
        uniform mat3 projectionMatrix;

        void main() {
            fColor = vColor;
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vPosition;
        }
    </script>

    <script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;
        varying  vec4 fColor;

        void main() {
            gl_FragColor = fColor;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the problem is. You're trying to assign a `vec3` to `gl_Position`, which is a `vec4`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Reto said,

> the error message tells you exactly what the problem is. You're trying to assign a `vec3` to `gl_Position`, which is a `vec4`

It even tells you the line number: `ERROR: 0:11` line 11

If we number the lines

```
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">1
 2    attribute vec3 vPosition;
 3    attribute vec4 vColor;
 4    varying vec4 fColor;
 5
 6    uniform mat3 modelViewMatrix;
 7    uniform mat3 projectionMatrix;
 8
 9    void main() {
10       fColor = vColor;
11       gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vPosition;
12    }
</script>
```

I'm guessing you want

```
gl_Position = vec4(projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vPosition, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I updated the vertex shader to use vec4 and mat4 objects insteas of vec3 and mat3. In the .js file, I changed all mat3 and vec4 objects accordingly as well. My old errors went away, but now I see the warning: [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:A03C0E92E87F0000]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0, supposedly in tangram.html : 1 (which is just a comment header with my name etc.). Any ideas?